# "No matching function call" when using generic methods

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a primitive generic method using void the problem is, the generic function gets pointers to functions and return also void* (I will show the code right away)

I tried to change the syntax few times. I think there's a problem with the stack or heap, I'm not sure.

```
void *get_structs_of_area(void *arr,
                          double area,
                          void*(*Allocation)(int size),
                          void*(*Get(void*, int)),
                          void(*Add(void*, void*)),
                          void(*Nullized(void*)),
                          double (* get_area)(void *))
{
    void* newArray = Allocation(N);
    Nullized(newArray);

    int cellUsed = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        if(get_area(Get(arr, i)) <=area)
        {
            Add(Get(arr, i), Get(newArray, cellUsed));
            cellUsed++;
        }
    return newArray;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
struct Circle* CircleAllocation(int size)
{
    struct Circle* tmp = new(nothrow)struct Circle[size];
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Allocation Failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return tmp;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void AddCircle(void* arr, void*newArr)
{
    struct Circle* x = (struct Circle*) arr;
    struct Circle* y = (struct Circle*) newArr;
    y = x;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
struct Circle* GetCircle(void* arr, int index)
{
    return (struct Circle*)arr+index;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
double getCirArea(void* cir)
{
    struct Circle* tmp = (struct Circle*)cir;
    return (tmp->_r * tmp->_r * 3.141);
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void NullCircle(void*arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        struct Circle* x = (struct Circle*)GetCircle(arr, i);
        x = NULL;
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void FreeCircle(void* arr)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < N; index++)
    {
        struct Circle* x = (struct Circle*)GetCircle(arr, index);
        delete[] x;
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main() {
    //example for arr of circle //
    struct Circle cirArr[N];

    cirArr[0]._center._x = 3;
    cirArr[0]._center._y = 3;
    cirArr[0]._r = 13;

    cirArr[1]._center._x = 17;
    cirArr[1]._center._y = 12;
    cirArr[1]._r = 5;

    //example for calling the function//
    struct Circle* newRec = (struct Circle*)get_structs_of_area(cirArr,
                        3.3,
                        CircleAllocation,
                        GetCircle,
                        AddCircle,
                        NullCircle,
                        getCirArea);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The message error:

> No matching function for call to 'get_structs_of_area'

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: _"i allowing myself to send the entire code since its really simple and short for expert programers like you guys!"_ While it is true that we are expert programmers, we are also very busy people and get many questions here that we volunteer our time to solve for free, so we'd appreciate it if you'd instead take the time to construct a [mcve]. Bonus: that's the best way to do debugging anyway, so you'll probably find the problem by making it.

Comment: _"i think there's a problem with the stack or heap, I'm not sure"_ Not if it's a compiler error about calling a function that doesn't exist! The compiler will be giving you more error detail in its output. When you present your [mcve] you should include _all_ the error detail, rather than just the first line.

Comment: oh hmm, because it is relevant to c, since its a method that using in c. in c++ there's classes, templates etc etc

Comment: @michael You removed the tag for the language that is actually being used

Comment: There are several features in this code that exist only in C++ (IOstreams, `new`, `delete`...). Therefore we can see that you _must_ be building it as C++. Therefore, it is not C.

Comment: (That being said, yes you should be using modern C++ idioms since you're writing C++ - lots of C-isms here!)

Comment: yep, but that's a college task so... he cannot do it in object oriented methods, that's another course haha

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -> Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @Eran Okay. Too bad!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why are you tagged `nullptr`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit lol my post is that bad? i can rewrite it, that's my first one tho

Comment: @SombreroChicken Inspired by your mum :D

Comment: @Eran Again, you need to condense it into a [mcve] please

Comment: No. @LightnessRacesinOrbit meant "too bad!" as in "ah that's a shame". It's a common term. (Like his mum is a common term.)

Comment: @Eran The problem is that the function parameters and passed arguments have different types as for example void*(*Allocation)(int size) and struct Circle* CircleAllocation(int size); and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i edited the post i hope its better now

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you! that means, our allocation functions for example should return void* as well? it wouldn't work that way?

Comment: @Eran Yes, The types of functions of arguments and parameters must coincide.

Comment: You need to fix the parentheses in the function declaration: `void *get_structs_of_area(void *arr, double area, void*(*Allocation)(int), void*(*Get)(void*, int), void(*Add)(void*, void*), void(*Nullized)(void*), double (* get_area)(void *));`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you! that was one of the issues!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp and that was the second issue haha, thanks!!!

Comment: Now it's missing symbols that make it fail to compile for reasons other than what you're asking about. Please read the page I linked you to to understand how to compose a [mcve].

Comment: Guys, don't write answers in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you have two problems. One is missing parenthesis. You need this:

```
void *get_structs_of_area(void *arr,
                      double area,
                      void*(*Allocation)(int size),
                      void*(*Get)(void*, int),
                      void((*Add)(void*, void*)),
                      void((*Nullized)(void*)),
                      double (* get_area)(void *))
```

The other is the type mismatch. If `get_structs_of_area` needs a function that returns a `void*`, somewhere there has to *be* a function that returns a `void*`. You can write wrapper functions that take the returned `struct Circle*` and cast it.